# apprequest fails to show up on user page

Tags: facebook, apprequests

I able to post apprequest with my app server-side (app generated) without error. Returns Id and user to. I used FQL tool to query using appid and userid and I get results. But when I go to my facebook page I don't have a notification nor do I see app on the left side with count. Can this be a setup issue (my first FB app)? I have the app in sandbox mode, does that have anything to do with it?

how your app integrates with Facebook setting has both Mobile Web and Canvas checked. This will be primarily a Mobile Web app.

I'm able to create posts and those show up.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Rick

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the issue here is sandbox mode.

Unless the user being sent the request is listed in the "roles" section of the application, the request won't really be sent out. The requests point back to your canvas URL, but with your application in sandbox mode, no one other than the team developing the application is able to reach that URL. Facebook doesn't display the notification because it wouldn't lead anywhere.

As far as you are concerned, the moment you get a request_id back after sending the request - it was completed successfully.